# iTunes Connect says my Icon.png file is 0x0.. it's clearly not!

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, app-store, app-store-connect

In my project directory, top level, I have Icon.png. Double-checked in Photoshop, it's 57x57. When I submit my application via iTunes Connect or Application Loader, I get an error message saying my icon file is 0x0. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've fixed this by now, but could it be related to the fact that you're saving in Photoshop, with a whole lot of metadata in there? I would suggest opening it in Preview (assuming Mac) and then saving it again, or perhaps saving as another (lossless) format and then back to the original file.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Turns out I had the Icons property in the plist set to "Icon.png".. when I cleared that field it worked.

Answer (score 6):

0x0 icon error i resolved by changed Compress PNGS to NO in project -> build settings

Answer (score 4):

This can also be caused by a change in OS X 10.7.3.  The fix in this case is to [download the latest version of the Application Loader](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1762/_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to set the file type of your icons to "Icon" than to turn off Xcode's PNG compression globally.